# Tomcat 7 occasionally returning 403 response

Tags: spring, authentication, tomcat7, http-status-code-403

I have an interesting issue occurring frequently in my Spring web app.  Basically, a user logs into the site successfully, navigates around to protected pages for a while and then for some reason, the server starts to return 403 responses.  The user calls into tech support and tech support asks them to refresh their browser and try again.  Magically, everything works fine the second time around after the refresh.  No one on my team is able to reproduce the issue in either our QA environment nor on Production.  Does anyone have any ideas what may cause this?

UPDATE - these are logs from the apache access log file

These calls are what prompt the call to tech support (notice the 403s)

```
"GET /server-webapp/api/getCartContents? HTTP/1.1" 200 1273
"GET /js/config.js HTTP/1.1" 200 809
"GET /server-webapp/api/getCartContents? HTTP/1.1" 200 1273
"GET /server-webapp/api/getUserInfo? HTTP/1.1" 200 201
"GET /server-webapp/api/getPendingSalesOrder? HTTP/1.1" 200 183
"POST /server-webapp/api/getShoppingCartErrors HTTP/1.1" 200 40
"GET /server-webapp/generated/CountriesAndStates.json? HTTP/1.1" 200 3319
"GET /server-webapp/api/getAddresses? HTTP/1.1" 403 390
"POST /server-webapp/api/createPendingSalesOrder HTTP/1.1" 403 390
"GET /server-webapp/api/getAddresses?" 403 390
"POST /server-webapp/api/createPendingSalesOrder HTTP/1.1" 403 390
"GET /server-webapp/api/getAddresses? HTTP/1.1" 403 390
"POST /server-webapp/api/createPendingSalesOrder HTTP/1.1" 403 390
```

The user is asked to refresh their browser and those same calls are now returning 200s...

```
"GET /server-webapp/api/getCartContents? HTTP/1.1" 200 1273
"GET /server-webapp/api/getCartContents? HTTP/1.1" 200 1273
"GET /server-webapp/api/getUserInfo? HTTP/1.1" 200 261
"POST /server-webapp/api/getShoppingCartErrors HTTP/1.1" 200 40
"GET /server-webapp/api/getPendingSalesOrder? HTTP/1.1" 200 183
"GET /server-webapp/generated/CountriesAndStates.json? HTTP/1.1" 200 3319
"GET /server-webapp/api/getAddresses? HTTP/1.1" 200 50
"POST /server-webapp/api/createPendingSalesOrder HTTP/1.1" 200 184
"POST /server-webapp/api/updatePendingSalesOrderLines HTTP/1.1" 200 42
"GET /server-webapp/api/getPendingSalesOrder? HTTP/1.1" 200 206
```

Comment: Wow, thats VERY vague... There are a LOT of reasons for something like that...  Can you be more specific perhaps? How about some logs from the request?

Comment: Yeah, I know its extremely vague, sorry.  I'll include as much of the logs as I can.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up not being with Tomcat or Apache and was, in fact, a nasty little bug in the authentication logic.  In short, the user was being logged in but with no permissions but only if they took a very specific route to becoming logged in.  Thanks to those that have taken a look and if there is way for me to delete the ticket then let me know since it turned out to be coding logic and not anything to do with Tomcat or Apache.